# python 3 TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

can u tell me what's wrong with this code?

```
 a=int(input())
 for i in range(a):
    lst=list(map(int,input().split(" ")))
    ans=lst[1]
    for j in range(lst[0]):
        ans=(ans(ans+1))/2
    print(ans)
```

And in output it shows-

```
line 6, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: `ans` is an `int`, yet you call it as if it were a function: `ans(ans+1)`. May be you meant to multiply here: `ans * (ans+1)`

Comment: thank u @schwobaseggl.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the line (considering you're trying to multiply them).Writing ans() makes the interpreter think ans is a function when in reality it is an int.

```
ans = (ans * (ans+1))/2
```